# jQuery jQuery-min conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

and let me tell you in advance that the no-conflict script didnt work either, my issue is this:

I have a site that i made, i made some animations for it, using the animate library and some other animations

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

//smoothscroll
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off("scroll");

    $('a').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var target = this.hash,
        menu = target;
    $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
    }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });
});
});


function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.nav-ul-home a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('.navbar-home ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}


$(window).scroll(function() {   





var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scroll > 100) {
    $(".navbar-home").addClass("navbar-section");
    $(".nav-ul-home").addClass("nav-ul-section");
}
else{
 $(".navbar-home").removeClass("navbar-section");
  $(".nav-ul-home").removeClass("nav-ul-section");
}
});



$(function() {
  var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
    this.el = el || {};
    // more then one submenu open?
    this.multiple = multiple || false;

var dropdownlink = this.el.find('.dropdownlink');
dropdownlink.on('click',
                { el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple },
                this.dropdown);


 };

  Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
    var $el = e.data.el,
        $this = $(this),
        //this is the ul.submenuItems
        $next = $this.next();

$next.slideToggle();
$this.parent().toggleClass('open');

if(!e.data.multiple) {
  //show only one menu at the same time
  $el.find('.submenuItems').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
}


 }

  var accordion = new Accordion($('.accordion-menu'), false);
})
```

and this is my animations script

```
$(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
   var top = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(),
       isVisible = top > $('#texto p').offset().top;
   $('#texto p').toggleClass('animated fadeInUp', isVisible);
});

$(window).on('scroll', function ($) {
   var top = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(),
       isVisible = top > $('in img').offset().top;
    $('in img').toggleClass('magictime tinRightIn', isVisible);
});

$(window).on('scroll', function ($) {
   var top = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(),
       isVisible = top > $('in p').offset().top;
    $('in p').toggleClass('magictime puffIn', isVisible);
});
```

I only put some of it cause it basically repeats its self for every case....

now... I have links to both jquery and jquery-min i need the jquery for this code and the jquery-min for the contact form, the problem is that when i have both links the animations dont work...
if i remove the jquery-min link everything is fine but the contact form doesnt work...

maybe if someone has a contact form template that has JS but doesnt need jquery-min the problem is solve..

sorry for my aqward way to post im prety new here.

thanks!

Comment: what jQuery version is the min and and what is the other ?

Comment: 3.2.1 both of them, I tried changing the versions, both at the same time or using different ones same thing

Comment: That doesn't sound very possible or is a bug in the minification.. There should be no difference between the min and not min file of the same version. Please check that both files load fine. Also post it live so we can test it.

Comment: Are you perhaps using the slim version ?

Comment: jquery.js and jquery-min.js is the same, `min` means minified (no space version). Just use 1 . My suggestion is if you still in dev process use jquery.js, but if you already in production use min.js

Comment: this is the contact form im using, if only there was a way for it to link to jquery and not to jquery-min it would solve all my problems!!  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IxZhVx1uYHTDmfpkoSl1p9euVtmLnx9a